Can a sequence converge to different points according to different topologies?
I've come up with a question while solving a Topology problem :

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x) = x/n$. Does the sequence $(f_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ converge in uniform topology? Does the sequence converge in compact convergence topology?

This is a part of an exercise problem from Munkres, section 46 #4. My claim is that the sequence $(f_n)$ is not convergent with the uniform topology. I can prove that it does not converge to $f \equiv 0$, but I think I have to further show that the sequence converge to nowhere.
Dealing with this problem, I came out with a question, or a hypothesis :

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ be two topological spaces, which are both Hausdorff. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$. If $(x_n)$ converges to $\alpha$ with respect to $\mathcal{T}_1$ and converges to $\beta$ with respect to $\mathcal{T}_2$, then $\alpha = \beta$.

Can someone help me with this? Just in case, the definition of convergence is as follows :

Definition. Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. A sequence $(x_n) \in X$ converges to $x\in X$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$, there exist $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \ge K$, then $x_n \in U$.


Can you think of a topology on $\Bbb R$ which is homeomorphic to the usual one, such that $1/n \to -1$? You will have to find a different way to argue for the problem you're trying to solve.

That claim is false. Consider any topological space $(X,\tau)$ with $(x_n)$ convergent to some $\alpha\in X$. Now pick any $\beta\in X$ and any bijection $f:X\to X$ such that $f(\alpha)=\beta$ and $f(x_n)=x_n$ for all $n$. Such bijection exists if $\alpha$ isn't present in $(x_n)$. More generally this works if $(x_n)$ doesn't have constant $\alpha$ subsequence (we can ignore finite occurrences of $\alpha$).
Then define new topology on $X$ via: $U$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\tau$. With that $f$ becomes a homeomorphism (in particular the new topology is Hausdorff if the old one was). Furthermore $f(x_n)=x_n$ converges to $f(\alpha)=\beta$.
What we've shown is that a sequence convergent in one topology can converge pretty much to any point in some topology, as long as it doesn't have a constant subsequence.
Convergent sequences that have constant subsequences of course have to have a single same limit, regardless of topology (as long as it is Hausdorff). Although it is not necessarily true that they converge in every topology. But if they do, then they always converge to the same limit.
So, as you can see this is rather rare property. And it won't help you in solving Munkres exercise.

Hello. I find this is a bit confusing, possibly due to editing artifacts, particularly with the existence of $f$, and $f(x_n) = x_n$, and non-eventually constant sequences. Do you mean "suppose $x_n \to \alpha$, and $\alpha$ occurs finitely often in $(x_n)$ (ie $(x_n)$ has no constant subsequence). Suppose $\beta$ also occurs finitely often in $(x_n)$. Let $f$ be the bijection swapping $\alpha$ and $\beta$. (...) Then because $x_n$ is eventually equal to $f(x_n)$, we have $x_n \to \beta$ in this new topology"?

@IzaakvanDongen if $\alpha$ occurs finitely many times in $(x_n)$ then we skip those $x_n$, meaning $f(x_k)=f(\alpha)=\beta$ has to hold. With that $y_n=f(x_n)$ sequence is slightly different from $(x_n)$ but it doesn't matter for convergence. I can again replace $y_n$ with $x_n$ for those finitely many points. The point is that this will break only when $\alpha$ occures infinitely many times in $(x_n)$. And due to convergence and Hausdorfness this can only mean $(x_n)$ being eventually constant. That's what I wanted to say. I will make a proper update later.

Yes, I understand the argument. I just mean that the sentence "Such bijection exists if $\alpha$ isn't present in $(x_n)$. In Hausdorff case that means that $(x_n)$ is not eventually constant (finite occurences of $\alpha$ can be ignored)." is a bit hard to follow for me. I still don't understand why you're talking about eventually constant sequences, I'm afraid (I think you mean "sequences with a constant subsequence"). Are you saying that if $\alpha$ occurs infinitely often in $x_n$ and $x_n \to \alpha$ then $x_n$ is eventually equal to $\alpha$? What about eg $x_n = \frac 1n(1 + (-1)^n)$?

@IzaakvanDongen ops, you're right. It should've been "constant subsequence". Fixed the answer.
